# Computing the value of a fraction involving summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

can we compute this term without using calculator?

$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+...+\frac{1}{997^2}+\frac{1}{999^2}-\frac{1}{1002^2}-\frac{1}{1004^2}-\frac{1}{1006^2}-...-\frac{1}{1998^2}-\frac{1}{2000^2}}{1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{999^2}+\frac{1}{1000^2}}$$

I can't see any pattern.

I tried to add and substract as mentioned in the comments but can't see how it helps.

thanks.

Comment: In the numerator add and substrate the even terms present in the denominator (1/2^2 +1/4^2+... ).

Comment: @incognito i tried that now but can't see how it helps.

Comment: @tammy: Now factor $4$ in the denominator of each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given fraction
$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+...+\frac{1}{997^2}+\frac{1}{999^2}-\frac{1}{1002^2}-\frac{1}{1004^2}-\frac{1}{1006^2}-...-\frac{1}{1998^2}-\frac{1}{2000^2}}{1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{999^2}+\frac{1}{1000^2}}$$
can be rewritten as
$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{999^2}+\frac{1}{1000^2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{1000^2}+\frac{1}{1002^2}+...+\frac{1}{1998^2}+\frac{1}{2000^2}\right)}{1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{999^2}+\frac{1}{1000^2}}$$
by adding and subtracting $\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{1000^2}$ to the numerator of the fraction. The above fraction can now be written as:
$$1 - \frac{\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{1000^2}+\frac{1}{1002^2}+\frac{1}{1004^2}+...+\frac{1}{1998^2}+\frac{1}{2000^2}}{1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+...+\frac{1}{999^2}+\frac{1}{1000^2}}$$

$$ = 1 - \frac{\frac{1}{2^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...+\frac{1}{999^2}+\frac{1}{1000^2}\right)}{1+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...+\frac{1}{999^2}+\frac{1}{1000^2}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^2} = \frac{3}{4}.$$